# Windows Azure: length of blob remains 0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm confused about how to get size of the blob in Windows Azure.

In my case, I first get the blob reference with `CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(foo);`(here foo is name of blob and I'm sure the blob exists). Then I try to get blob size `blob.Property.Length;` However, it always return `0`. I breakpoint at this statement and track content inside `blob`: `uri` of the blob is correct, can I infer that the blob is correctly retrieved from that? While all the fields in `Properties` is either `null` or `0`. I cannot figure out a solution. Is it because I currently emulate the app locally in `Storage Emulator` and will be OK after the deployment?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Call `blob.FetchAttributes()`. `GetBlockBlobReference` doesn't actually make any calls to the blob service. It just constructs a local object that represents the blob.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a blog on exact same issue about 4 days back:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/04/27/windows-azure-blob-size-return-0-even-when-blob-is-accessible-and-downloaded-without-any-problem.aspx